# HttpUrlConnection class performs GET despite setting POST as method type

Tags: java, post, https, get, httpurlconnection

I am trying to hit an API which has both GET and POST request handlers.
While I am trying to perform GET request, which is as follows :

```
HttpsURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpURLConnection.connect();
```

I get proper *Cookies* as well *HTML* response.

But now I try to perform POST request on the same url as follows :

```
String postBody = "__RequestVerificationToken=" + __RequestVerificationToken + "&Username=" + userName
            + "&Password=" + passWord;
byte[] postData = postBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

HttpsURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.length));
httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);

/**
 * write the request body as bytes
 */
OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
os.write(postBody.getBytes());
os.flush();
os.close();
```

All I get in *Cookies* and *HTML Response* is ditto to what I received in GET request earlier.

Can someone please explain what is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

```
<!-- language: java -->
String postBody = "__RequestVerificationToken=" + __RequestVerificationToken + "&Username=" + userName
            + "&Password=" + passWord;
byte[] postData = postBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

HttpsURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.length));
httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);

/**
 * write the request body as bytes
 */
OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
os.write(postBody.getBytes());
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Comment: Where exactly ? At the time of POST call ?

Comment: `
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
...
`